# Unique ID to transfer guest account data from Adobe AIR to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, flash, air, uniqueidentifier

I am migrating my app from Adobe AIR to Unity. I have many users logged in as guests in my current AIR app. When I release the new Unity app, their progress and data will be lost. Is there any way to keep their data synced when they finish the update? I know that the device id I used in AIR won't be the same as the Unity one.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use app-storage folder to write down some persistent data? I believe that app-storage is not wiped on app update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the native extension developer company and they released a Unity version, supporting the same id. It's resolved now.